# System.debug(JSON.Serialize(o)) Not longer shows full string

Tags: debug-logs

For the longest time I have been using `System.debug(JSON.Serialize(o))` to output objects to the debug log for troubleshooting purposes. This has worked up until my most recent project. Even existing code seems to be having this behavior.

I've tested API versions 41-45 with no luck. The actual line of code I'm using is:

```
system.debug(json.serialize(accountsToInsert)); // This is a map
```

I have also tried:

```
system.debug(json.serialize(accountsToInsert.get(Key)));
```

AND

```
Account test = accountsToInsert.get(Key);
system.debug(json.serialize(test));
```

The code is called from a method defined in a VF page `action` attribute.

Is this just a thing that we have to live with now? Is there another way to get a  full look into the state of an object at run time?

Comment: Why not use [Apex Replay Debugger](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger)?

Comment: As far as I have seen somewhere here, SF started to cut length of string in system.debug in Spring'19

Comment: @JayantDas Mostly just because I haven't had the time to learn it but if I have to I have to. I only recently got started with VS Code :P

Comment: And here is a proof  @gNerb -- https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_developer_console.htm

Comment: @kurunve I think that's the best answer, if you want to post an answer Ill accept it.

Comment: This came up recent in [Developer Console suddenly truncating System.Debug output](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/255068/102)

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks, I didn't find those when I went looking. When I googled after asking my own question my question is the one that came up so I mistakenly thought I was first. The answer to this question, to me, is much more complete then the other 2 in that it gives several, ootb solutions provided by Salesforce to help achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, since Spring'19 in order to improve performance, Salesforce changed a way how long strings are shown in the Developers Console.

Now strings are now truncated at 512 characters in the Developer Console’s Log Inspector

In order to retrieve full log, it is needed to use **Open Raw Log** in Developers Console menu.

Release notes with more information – https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_developer_console.htm

Some Suggestions:

- The [Apex Replay Debugger](http://Apex%20Replay%20Debugger) is a powerful debugging tool - **Note** Seems to have issues with very large debug logs.
- [Checkpoints](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/developer_console/developer_console_checkpoints) can be used to inspect objects at given points in code using the developer console.
- [Apex Interactive Debugger](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/interactive-debugger/) - This has become my personal favorite debugging tool.

Comment: For completeness, I combined the other answers into a single post. I'm heading down the path of the replay debugger as my solution.

Comment: thanks @gNerb. Personally sometimes I use apex snippet to create a Document with given body if it is a size of 2-3mb

Comment: Updated with references to the Apex Interactive Debugger since this question seems to be a popular one.

Answer (score 13):

I always recommend using [Checkpoints](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5); this gives you an easy way to inspect the entire heap (memory). You can learn more about this in the trailhead [Inspect Objects at Checkpoints](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/developer_console/developer_console_checkpoints). Simply open the Developer Console, open the class you want to inspect (e.g. your controller), and click on the left-side gutter for the point you'd like to set the checkpoint. The checkpoints will appear in the Checkpoints tab in the Developer Console when you perform the action.

Comment: This is great information, but I think that Karune has the actual answer. +1 though.

Comment: Does this work for apex that gets invoked from UI? because after my ui is finished rendering I dont get details loaded in lthe panel left side to checkpoint location